# Generating new objects when using numpy choice on a list of objects

Tags: python, numpy, oop, random

I have a list of objects. I use numpy choice with replacement to choose a number of objects from the list. The problem is that I am generating multiple references to the same object. What I want is to generate an altogether a list of *new* objects.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
class agent:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
parents = []
parents.append(agent("John"))
parents.append(agent("Max"))
parents.append(agent("Alex"))
select_probs = [0.4, 0.3, 0.3]
new_generation = list(np.random.choice(people, 5, replace = True, p = select_probs))
print(new_generation)
# example of output
# [<__main__.agent object at 0x000001F360DC0760>, 
#  <__main__.agent object at 0x000001F360DC03D0>, 
#  <__main__.agent object at 0x000001F360DC0760>, 
#  <__main__.agent object at 0x000001F360DC0760>, 
#  <__main__.agent object at 0x000001F360DC03D0>]
```

As you can see, my choices, 0, 2, 3 are the same object. I want them to be different people. Think about 0x000001F360DC0760 as the parent, and the chosen objects as offspring.

Any suggestions how I can use numpy choice to generate new objects, instead of references to the old objects?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `numpy.choice` to begin with? use the standard library `random` module for this.

Comment: In any case, none of these functions will **ever** implicitly copy the objects. If you want that to happen, you have to handle that yourself somehow (mabe just `new_generation = [copy.copy(person) for person in new_generation]`, or even `[agent(a.name) for a in new_generation]`

Comment: The issue is not with the choice function. The issue is that when I choose the same object it creates another reference to the same object. You wouldn't have this problem if you were choosing integers, for example. I need independent copies, not multiple references to the same copy.

Comment: You **absolutly would have the same problem** if you were working with python objects, i.e. a list of `int` objects (of course, it shouldnt' be a problem for immutable objets). This is pretty fundamental to Python. If you work with `numpy.ndarray` objects, that is different, because they are basically wrappers around primitive arraays.  It doesn't make sense to use `numpy.random` with python lists, that is my only point, in either case, though both functions will work the same

Comment: [copy.copy(person) for person in new_generation] solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: You could `choice` on the names, and then make fresh objects from those.

Comment: Yes, that's also a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution above is almost exactly what I needed with one minor correction: I need to use deepcopy instead of "shallow" copy:

```
new_generation = [copy.deepcopy(person) for person in new_generation]
```

Comment: well, no, you don't, not in the example you posted.